# Append acts and scenes of a drama (text file) to a given list structure (nested lists)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append, nested-lists

(Using Python 3.5 on Windows) Hey, I'm trying to append the acts and scenes of a drama to a given list structure. It's part of a project, where i want to create a social network for several dramas (written by Goethe). Since the structures of the dramas are mostly consistent, it is possible to put them all in the same pattern. The structure i created is the following:
For every utterance of a character, I created a tuple, in which i put the character name and the utterance, e.g. ('Peter:', 'How are you?'). Then the drama has five acts and every act has a various number of scenes. 
What i want to do now:
Creating a list structure, which looks like this:

```
drama = [[act_x[scene_x[utterance_x(role, text), utterance_y(role, text),...],

                scene_y[utterance_x(role, text), utterance_y(role, text),...],...] 

         [act_y[scene_x[utterance_x(role, text), utterance_y(role,text),...],...],...]
```

With my data it would be:

```
print(drama)
output:
[[[[('Peter:', 'How are you?'), ('Mike:', 'I'm fine, thanks.'), ('Peter:', 'I have to go.')]
[('Maria:', 'Did you hear what happened?'), ('Tina:', 'Yes, it's horrible. I saw it with 
my own eyes')]] [[('James:', 'It was great to meet you.'), ('Maria:', 'I hope we will meet 
again one day. Farewell!')]]]]
```

Notice, that 'act', 'scene' and 'utterance' are only used here for clarification. The only real elements in the lists are the tuples (role, text). After the whole drama is stored in this list, i could sccess every single utterance. For example i want third act, fifth scene, sixth utterance, i call: drama[2][4][5].
Everytime one line contains 'act' i want to append the acts list to the drama list and everytime one line contains 'scene' i want to append the scenes list to the acts list and the utterance list (which contains the tuples) to the scenes list. So far so good, but when i append the lists to each other I always get a structure like this [[[[(role, text)]]], [[[(role, text)]]],...
What is the right way to get the above explained structure?

```
drama = []
acts = []
scenes = []
utterances = []
speakerandspeech = ()
for line in f:
...#doing all the needed sorting stuff
speakerandspeech = (temp_list[0], ' '.join(temp_list[1:])) #templist[0] is role, templist[1:] is text
utterances.append(speakerandspeech)
scenes.append(utterances)
acts.append(scenes)
drama.append(acts)
utterances = []
scenes = []
acts = []
```

Comment: What is your original input data?

Comment: The input data is a .txt file which contains the whole drama. I open it and read it line by line

Comment: Could you post a small sample with what your desired output looks like from that input?

Comment: I added the intended output in the post

Comment: Could you provide a small (maybe two lines) sample of your input data and post your entire script (e.g. fill in the blanks where "doing all the needed sorting stuff" is)?
It is unclear where `temp_list` comes from and how to get access to the text to figure out where acts end and start etc.